# Não consigo utilizar o debug em uma library

Tags: java, android, android-eclipse

Preciso debugar uma lib que acabei de criar, já fiz esses passos:

> *Here is what worked for me: (After having clicked debug at least once before) Open the debug view in eclipse (use the menu at the top:
>   Window -> Show View -> Debug)
>
> Right click one of the activities in the debug window "Edit source
>   lookup" Click "Add" Select "Java Project" Check the box for the
>   Android Library project Press OK*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas mesmo assim não entra na LIB, podem me ajudar a saber qual pode ser o problema?